# How to track and implement cancel option for nested Runnable in java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am working on a Java application which uses `ZMQ` to handle request. My code have some nested `Runnable` which are as in following structure:

```
private class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                createProcess();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //handled
            }
        }
    }
}

public void createProcess(){
    ZMsg receivedRequest = receiveReq(); // wait for request
    Runnable workerRunnable = new WorkerRunnable(receivedRequest, this);
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerRunnable);
    workerThread.start();
}
```

So Each time I send a request using `Fiddler`, it will create new `WorkerRunnable` and pass the `zmq` request to it for futher processing.
This WorkerRunnable is defined as :

```
private class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                // do something with received request
                switch(type) : 
                case EXECUTE:
                    startExecution(); // this will internally create one more thread
                    break;

                case STOP:
                    stopExecution();
                    break;                      
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //handled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the very simple workflow:

1. I made a request using `fiddler` to execute something. It will create one WorkerRunnable.
2. In next request I want to stop the `WorkerRunnable` started in step 1.

It may happen that I made multiple request then among them I want to stop any one request. How to track all WorkerRunnable and how to interrupt them if request comes to stop them?
I tried `ExecutorService` but didn't found any exact way to use it in this scenario. Please suggest proper way to do that.

Comment: Not an answer but - what benefit are you achieving by spawning a thread within a thread? Have you thought about context switching overheads? Also you might want to look into `Thread.interupt()`

Comment: @Skynet In WorkerRunnable it will do some conversions in Java and then a call is made into Python then it will come back to java, some conversions again and then response is sent back to user. Also user can send multiple request and if request is taking too much time to execute User want to Cancel a particular request. So thread spawning is what came into my mind. Also, since I am unable to track all the Runnable, i dont know how to interrupt a particular Runnable/Thread. Any idea??

Comment: I really see threads within threads as a 'Red Alert' and bad program design. Its opinion based but, consider debugging/ maintenance hell and the situation you are in right now! :) I would design this from point A to B on a single thread for each request.

Comment: @Skynet It will be helpful if you provide a rough design in answer to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: What does WorkerRunnable do? Does it update a database? Write to a file? Insert into a queue? What exactly does it do? Inorder to revert something you might have to have a mapping.

Comment: "In next request I want to stop the WorkerRunnable started in step 1."
No way. WorkerRunnable executes either startExecution() or stopExecution(), both calls run quickly, and by the time you decide to stop  the WorkerRunnable, it is definitely finished.

Comment: @Skynet It is changing the ZMQ request to way python interface looks for input and then converts the output from python call into the way user wants to see.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Well its kind of long running task which usually takes 30 to 45 seconds to complete.

Comment: What are you trying to cancel in `It is changing the ZMQ request to way python interface looks for input and then converts the output from python call into the way user wants to see` ??

Comment: @Skynet Since python thing is not my control i want to cancel the thread(WorkerRunnable) which is handling that request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a *[thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)* in your `createProcess()` function?  If you used a pool, then you could submit [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) 
tasks to the pool, and get back [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instances. Then, depending on how you implemented your `Callable` objects, you potentially could use the `Future.cancel()` method to abort a task.

Comment: Future.cancel() does not guarantee killing. I tried this also, even it interrupts, but my code keeps on executing.

Comment: @techie, That is why I said, "depending on how you implemented your `Callable` objects." `future.cancel(true)` will deliver an interrupt to the worker thread if the task was running, and it will mark the `future` as cancelled, but it's up to you to write an implementation of the `Callable` object that will notice the interrupt and stop whatever it was doing.